# Jquery disable toggle div if timeout

Tags: javascript, jquery, scroll, settimeout

In my page after 5 seconds, a div collapse with setTimeout function, and also if the user scroll, the div collapse. I use slideUp and slideDown.
If the timeout is started, the div is closed, but if the user scrolls the div opens and then closes again. I want to disable the opening of the first div with scroll if the div is closed automatically by setTimeout function

```
<div class="divCollapse">Text here</div>

$( document ).ready(function() {        
        var timer;
        if(!$(window).scrollTop()) {    
         timer = setTimeout(function(){ $('.divCollapse').slideUp();}, 5000);
        } 
        $(window).scroll(function() {               
                if ($(this).scrollTop()>10){                    
                   $('.divCollapse').slideUp();
                    clearTimeout(timer);
                }
                else{                     
                   $('.divCollapse').slideDown();                        
                }           
        });          
    });
```

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
var timer;
if ($(window).scrollTop() <= 10) {
    timer = setTimeout(function () {
        $('.divCollapse').slideUp();
    }, 5000);
}
$(window).bind('scroll.collapse', function () {
    if ($(this).scrollTop() > 10) {
        $('.divCollapse').slideUp();
        clearTimeout(timer);
        timer = false;
    } else if (!timer) {
        $('.divCollapse').slideDown();
    }
});
```

Comment: My JQuery version is 1.5 and in console i've this errors

TypeError: $(...).on is not a function

TypeError: $(...).off is not a function

Comment: so use bind() instead of on() and unbind() instead of off(), or better, upgrade your jquery to newer version... There is no reason to still use jq 1.5. For support of old plugins, use jquery migrate to upgrade them

Comment: Ok for error, but now if the div disappears with setTimeout if i scroll down and after top the div doesn't appears

Comment: So improve your question because reading it i was thinking it was the expected result. But i don't really understand what you are looking for. Provide a jsfiddle and explain expected result more clearly

Comment: I really don't understand this part: "If the timeout is **started** (do you mean if timeout callback is called???), the div is closed, but if the user scrolls the div opens and then closes again. **I want to disable the opening of the first div with scroll** if the div is closed automatically by setTimeout function"  As i understand it, this is exactly how the jsfiddle works

Comment: Ok, i think i understand what you mean, i'll check to find a workaround

Comment: When user scrolls after timeout, the div no opens. This way it's wrong. 
If the div autocloses, when the user scrolls the div must be open